# mysql somehow group and then select from tag map

Tags: mysql

The table:

```
| tag_id | article_id |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 100        |
|--------|------------|
| 2      | 100        |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 200        |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | 300        |
```

How could I select only two first rows

The logic: 
select ONLY articles
that have
tag_id 1 AND 2

in this case it is article with id 100

I could use php to filter results, but mysql usually is neater.

Comment: There is so much missing here... but, with what you wrote, you could use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY article_id LIMIT 2`

You could also do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE article_id = 100`.

Once again, I'd like to underline how silly it is to give answer without having a meaningful question :).

Comment: There is no default order in a table. If you don't have another column indicating the order ....

Comment: I need a list of articles whose IDs I don't know. 

There are other fields that indicate order in this table, but for simplicity I omitted them. How would date or any other field help?

Comment: So you want the article IDs that have a tag id of both 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the article_ids that have both tag_id 1 and 2 you can use a where clause combined with a group by clause limited by a having clause like this:

```
select article_id 
from your_table
where tag_id in (1,2)
group by article_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2;
```

With your sample table this would return article_id = 100.

Note that this would return articles that don't just have tag_id 1 and 2, but also those articles that have tag_id 1 and 2 plus other tags - it just limits the result to those articles that have *at least* tag_id 1 and 2 (but could have more). If you want to limit to those articles that have only tag_id 1 and 2 then you could add a correlated exists predicate for instance.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ed24/2)

Comment: Thank you - this works for me. Even in my actual more complex query this works: SELECT * FROM  `table1` CROSS JOIN `table2` ON table1.article_id = table2.article_id WHERE tag_id IN (6,14,2) group by article_id having count(distinct tag_id) = 3

Comment: @ArmandP Happy it worked. Know that with MySQL a `cross join` with a `on` clause will be treated as an `inner join`, which is probably what you want to use anyway.

Comment: In the end I used this solution in combination with EXISTS (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/exists-predicate) because some tags are required and some are not . @jpw thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT article_id FROM table_name WHERE tag_id IN (1,2);
```

Comment: This would return all rows from the sample table, not just those articles that have _both_ tag_id 1 and 2.